# export .bib and files with bib2html

Tags: bibdesk

I organize my references with bibdesk, most entries have files attached to them.

I am using `bib2bib` (which is part of [bib2html](https://www.lri.fr/%7Efilliatr/bibtex2html/)) to export smaller bibliographies based on keyword with a `sh` script, here is an example:

```
bib2bib -ob subset.bib -c 'Keywords : "subset"' allBibEntries/allBibEntries.bib
```

I would like to also save a folder with the files linked to an entry in the same directory (or a subfolder) in which `subset.bib` is saved.

Is there a command-line way to save the attached files from a `.bib` file organized with Bibdesk (so using the information in the `bdsk-file-x` fields?

I'm not wedded to using `bib2html` if there's an alternative way...

Answer (score 0):

This works on my computer:
`bibtool -r bibtoolrsc -X /path/to/your/library.bib -i %f -e '.*' -d /path/to/save/files/`